# Can i run multiple applications on SQL Server 2012 Developer Editions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

We want to reduce the load of our production server.

So we decide to install a developer edition(we have a 2012 edition) to a different server to do tests.

I hear about the developer edition only allows to have one client.

So i want to know:
Can i run app A and app B which all need to connect the developer DB, at the same time on the testing server?

How about the multiple threads/ connections part?

Also, how about if server running some app, 
and Can i run app from my local computer connect to the developer DB?

Comment: The licensing of developer edition is per developer - not per machine - which may complicate things (time to call your MS rep) I can't see any _technical_ problems running it as you're intending.

Comment: how about if server running some app, and Can i run app from my local computer connect to the developer DB?